# Change only one property of State şin React

Tags: reactjs, state, react-state

I want to just change only one item of the state which have 2 items in React. Here is the code.

```
//İnitial
const initialState ={
  status:"",
  gender:""
}
//Creating State
const [searchTerm,setSearchTerm]=useState(initialState);

//Callback function in select on change
const setStatusFilter=(event)=>{
setSearchTerm(prev=>(
{
  status:event.target.value,
  ...prev.gender
}))
}

const setGenderFilter=(event)=>{
setSearchTerm(prev=>(
{
    ...prev.status,
    gender:event.target.value

}))
```

}

I use this state to fetch API. But when I change one of them, other one becomes undefined, but it must be the previous value.
So fetch is broken. I did not understand why it is happening.

Answer (score 3):

Use the spread operator on `prev` directly, and then just add other fields you want to update.

```
setSearchTerm(prev => ({...prev, status: event.target.value}))
```

You were trying to spread `...prev.status` but `status` is just a string value, not an object.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Feel free to accept the answer and upvote for other people to see in the future as valid one. Thanks!